# How to expose RabbitMQ AMQP URL deployed on kubernetes to outside the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, bitnami

I created a RabbitMQ cluster on AKS using Bitnami's packaged RabbitMQ from Azure's marketplace.
Using [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) I can expose RabbitMQ's admin panel without a problem using this Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rabbit
  namespace: rabbit
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rabbit.myapi.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rabbitclusterextension-rabbitmq
            port:
              number: 15672
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

If I change the port to 5672 to connect a client to the cluster It doesn't work. I read that it is because Nginx Ingress Controller can only expose HTTP and HTTPS and as we know RabbitMQ is served using AMQP protocol.

So my question is how can I expose an AMQP URL so my clients can connect to the cluster from outside the cluster?

Comment: AMQP utilizes TCP/IP connection and you expose http in rules. You need to expose tcp service, like here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md

Comment: I actually tried it at first but had the wrong namespace on my configmap haha 
Your comment made me try again and it worked. 
Now my problem is enabling TLS (AMQPS), but that's another issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the instructions carefully https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md

I had the wrong namespace on my configmap at first.